# JAVA NoClassDefFoundError issue

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt

I am new to Java and trying to create GUI projects using SWT and JFace. I wanted to try out creating preferences page, so I Googled and got some ready made codes. I am trying the one from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JFacepreferences.htm). I created the class (with correct name) and put required jars in plug-in dependencies. (Using Eclipse Oxygen)

1. org.eclipse.swt_3.106.1
2. org.eclipse.core.commands_3.9.0
3. org.eclipse.jface_3.13.1

So while running this I got an error saying:

> 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/Assert'.
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert

Thinking that it is not finding the plugins at runtime I added them here as well

> Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables.

But the issue is still there. What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.core.commands` can only be used in an Eclipse plugin, it will not work in a plain Java application.

JFace has some basic support for preference pages but most of the code you find will use the extended version of the preference pages which only runs in an Eclipse plugin.

When looking for code you need to distinguish between things that only use SWT+JFace and things which use other Eclipse plugins and can only run as a plugin. If you want to use everything you will need to write an Eclipse RCP rather than an ordinary Java app.

Comment: Hi Greg, as I said I am new to Java so you might want to elaborate that a bit. I got that you are advising to create a plug-in project as the preferences work for that only. But being a newbie to Java I copy-pasted the same code in a plugin project and hoped it will work! Of course, it didn't. Could you please give more details?

Comment: That is far too broad for a Stack Overflow answer. To use Eclipse plugin code you have to write your entire application as plugins - probably a RCP (Rich Client Product). So if you just want a plain Java app you can't use the plugin code.

Comment: OK, I tried creating a sample Plugin project with preference pages as a template. It came with a sample preference page as well which contributes to already existing pages. It worked, obviously, and now I will try and integrate my preference editors in it. Thanks.